# what is the equivalent for $d' = 0$ for 3D surfaces to detect "pinches"?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

with a given function in $R^2$ you can detect a "pinch" in the graph when the first derivative is zero and assume that the graph is "smooth" when the same first derivative is not zero: what is the equivalent condition to detect a so visible change in the 3D surface in linear algebra ? There is a matrix for that capable of computing a value that "drives" the detection like the first derivative in $R^2$ functions ?

EDIT: in my case

3D surface = set of 3D coordinates, not a function, or a manifold, or anything else, just a set of vertices.

Comment: I suggest you to read about maximum and minimum and Jacobian for two variables function.

Comment: @Sigur so this is a good read for this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant ?

Comment: Maybe this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative

Comment: @Sigur ok, maybe I'm not describing this perfectly, but with a 3D surface I mean a "set of 3D coordinates that describe a surface", and not a function, in other words this points are not generated by a math law, they are just a set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just have a set of vertices, then you don't have a surface until you triangulate them to form a mesh. After you have the mesh, you can find "pinches" or other anomalies by comparing triangle normals along edges or at vertices.

There is no analogue of the $d' = 0$ criterion because you don't have any differentiable functions that describe your "surface".

Your question is about the field of "discrete differential geometry". If you search for this term, you'll find lots of useful references. In particular [these notes](http://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs468-10-fall/LectureSlides/05_Diff_Geo.pdf) seem quite good. The first 43 slides are about classical differential geometry. The part that's of interest to you starts on slide #44. I suspect that a "pinch" can be detected by examining curvature, which is covered on slide #55.

Comment: thanks for that, the gradient can be a possible solution ?